# Excel VBA - Application.OnTime not working and WScript.Shell.PopUp timer not working

Tags: vba, excel, popup, wsh

I have an automated task that will open Excel and run some VBA code at a specific time every morning. If a user has the excel file open I want to warn them the file will be automatically closed in a few moments via a popup message, then shortly thereafter have Excel automatically save and quit. In case the user is away from their computer, I want the popup message to close automatically after 5 seconds so it doesn't freeze my `SaveExit` subroutine.

**The popup message is appearing, but it will not close automatically.**
It is only closing if "OK" is clicked. This is preventing the `SaveExit` routine from running.

Under `Microsoft Excel Objects` in `This Workbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pull Data").Activate
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("1:00:00 AM"), "CloseWarn", TimeValue("1:02:00 AM")
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("1:03:00 AM"), "SaveExit", TimeValue("1:04:00 AM")
End Sub
```

In a `module` called `autoclose`:

```
Sub SaveExit()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
    .Save
    Application.Quit
End With
End Sub

Sub CloseWarn()
Select Case CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp("closing soon", 5, "Warning")
    Case 1, -1
End Select
End Sub
```

**How do I get a popup warning message to display at a specific time, then close if no user input occurs??**

Comment: Have you tried creating your own form, opening that form as a pop up and then in that form coding the time limit? This will give you much more versatility than the provided pop up.

Comment: no i have not. i'll give it a shot.

Comment: @evan i can't get a form to work either. when i put an `unload me` command in the form code using `Application.OnTime` or `Application.Wait`, nothing happens. when i try to use another sub to call the form then unload it using `Application.OnTime`, it works... but when i try to initiate that sub from an `Application.OnTime` command in the `Workbook_Open` routine, it says "the macro isn't available or macros are not enabled".

Comment: Thats interesting.... The logic seems sound. Perhaps trying to add the ontime event after the form opens rather than workbook_open. So add `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "CloseWarningForm"` inside of the `CloseWarn()` procedure

Comment: It would help to show the code you're using to show and close your custom form.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've figured out a solution that seems to work. I've posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Thanks @Evan for pointing me in the right direction. I don't understand why, but when using the `Application.OnTime` command under `Workbook_Open`, things work better if I identify the module where the routine is located. After I figured this out I moved my subs to `ThisWorkbook` to streamline my code. I created a `userform` called `CloseAlert` that informs users that Excel is about to close automatically. The userform closes after 5 seconds, or upon user clicking "OK".

Under `Microsoft Excel Objects` in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pull Data").Activate
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:08:00"), "ThisWorkbook.ShowCloseAlert"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:09:00"), "ThisWorkbook.SaveExit"
End Sub

Private Sub ShowCloseAlert()
CloseAlert.Show vbModeless
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Unloadit"
End Sub

Sub SaveExit()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
    .Save
    Application.Quit
End With
End Sub
```

In a separate `module` called `unload_CloseAlert`:

```
Public Sub Unloadit()
unload CloseAlert
End Sub
```